# SSAS cube deployment fails but no errors are shown in error list

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

I'm developing a simple cube based on the AdventureWorksDW2012 database. I am using Visual Studio 2012 with SSDT installed. I'm facing a weird issue when the deployment to the Analysis services fails but the cause of the failure is not important. In the error list I see the number of errors and warnings (2 errors and 11 warnings), but no errors are displayed in the list. I see nothing in the output window neither.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an image of the output and any warnings? What you have posted is not enough to give intelligent answers that aren't just random guessing.

Comment: I've tried to do that, but I don't have enough reputation to post images..

Comment: Can you post a link?  Someone else can edit it to add the image into your post.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the error list, with 1 error and 2 warnings
http://s15.postimg.org/ft1h3mshn/Capture.png

Comment: I'd like to point out that even with other types of errors, such as build errors, I still don't see anything in the error list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how there's a blue line around the filter at the top left? [image]

or in your case

[image]

That means filtering of the errors list is ON.

Turn it off by turning off all checkmarks in here:

[image]